# My Zoom screen is no longer sharing on my Mac

Tags: mac, security, screen, privacy

As host, I used to be able to share my screen, documents and presentation, but now I cannot.

On my end, I see the share screen with "empty" files to share. On the attendees end, they see a black screen.

I have a Mac and have uninstalled and reinstalled Zoom twice, but I am still having this problem. I have a HUGE client presentation this Friday.

Can anyone assist me? Thanks!

Comment: What version of macOS? Have you updated to the latest release of Zoom?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that zoom has the right permissions?

Open Preferences > Security & Privacy > Screen Recording and check that zoom.us.app is **allowed** to record your screen. [image: Preferences > Security & Privacy > Screen Recording]

Also check on Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access an allow zoom.us.app access. [image: Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access]

Lastly, check Preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders and check that zoom.us.app has access to the download folder (presumably to receive files).

[image: Preferences > Security & Privacy > Files and Folders]

I don't know if allowing only access to this folder and then moving the files you want to share there may allow you to send and receive without allowing Full Disk Access that seems excessive.